# displayIfNeeded do nothing on Big Sur

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos-big-sur

I need to maximize compatibility for a program that I want it to works from 10.6 to Big Sur. That's why I use XCode 3.2.2.

It seems to work on Big Sur but the function [nswind displayIfNeeded];

it doesn't do anything.

displayIfNeeded instance method still available I see on apple.com but do nothing.

I need this function to redraw portions of the window that become dirty by use.

Before displayIfNeeded I invalidate rect with: setNeedsDisplayInRect

Minimal code:

```
# window init
NSWindow *NSWind=[super initWithContentRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, g_winw, g_winh) styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled | NSWindowStyleMaskMiniaturizable | NSWindowStyleMaskResizable | NSWindowStyleMaskClosable backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
  
NSView *GPview = [[GRAPH alloc]initWithFrame: NSMakeRect(0, 0, s_winw, s_winh-g_menuh)];
[GPview setAutoresizingMask: NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable];
[[self contentView] addSubview:GPview]; 

# User action 
[GPview setNeedsDisplayInRect: NSMakeRect(r->left,g_winh-(r->bottom-r->top)-r->top,r->right-r->left,r->bottom-r->top)];
  
[NSWind displayIfNeeded];
```

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: I updated, please check it

Comment: Is r bottom > r top ? Whatever r is.

Comment: Why do you call `setNeedsDisplay` and `displayIfNeeded` on two different views?

Comment: Both `setNeedsDisplayInRect` and `displayIfNeeded` shouldn't be needed on a new view. From where do you run the code? Is this a regular window in a Cocoa app? `NSWindow *NSWind=[super initWithContentRect:` doesn't look right. Is an override in `GRAPH` the cause of the issue?

Comment: Thanks, That was the mistake, thanks. setNeedsDisplay and displayIfNeeded must be on the same view